# Run laptop's HDD through USB

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, usb

My laptop went kaput. I want to take my laptop's HDD and boot the OS (Windows 7) in a different computer through a USB adapter. Possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "run"? Do you mean access the files on it? Or do you mean boot from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just get a cheap USB external enclosure that's appropriate for your hard drive type. (IDE or SATA)

Comment: How can I tell between IDE and SATA? Is it a very noticeable hardware difference?

Comment: Check the documentation for your laptop or look at the hard drive. If it has [two flat connectors](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/4371i4C980915929EBBB9/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1) (one for power, one for data), it's SATA. If it has [one wide connector with two rows of pins sticking out](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/4369i56FBEA46A0BD3FF0/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1), it's IDE.

Comment: I meant booting the OS. I've clarified the question as well.

Comment: You may need to go into the BIOS on the computer you intend to use to change the boot order.  It may not by default boot from the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Won't always work though. If windows notices too big of a change in hardware, it won't load up the proper drivers and it will fall. As well, make sure the new laptop supports USB booting

Comment: Is there anyway to fix the driver problem?

Comment: It's a very long manual process, and depends on the old system and the new one. Due to the tine it would take to do it, it's usually not worthit

Comment: Windows won't boot from USB anyway.

Comment: @kinokijuf There are ways to

Comment: @Luke there aren’t. Windows resets the USB ports during the boot sequence, which would mean losing access to the boot device.

Comment: @kinokijuf However, just like Ubuntu, W7 and W8 can be installed and boot from USB. Wouldn't the same principle apply here?

Comment: @drum W8 yes (see Windows to Go) W7 no (install only).